# Standard deviation in generated data with specified autocorrelation - correction factor?

Tags: r, standard-deviation, autocorrelation, bias-correction, data-generating-process

I want to generate time-series data with specified AR(1) and standard deviation.
I am using arima.sim to generate univariate time series.
*(Ultimately, I want to use `VAR.sim` in `tsDyn` package for multivariate data, but I will keep it simple here with arima.sim for demonstration in a univariate situation).*

I noticed that when AR is higher, the standard error will also be higher. A correction factor is needed to estimate the standard deviation.

This was discussed in both Section 1.1 of Beran (1994) and Bence (1995).

In Beran (1994)'s discussion on correction factor *c(a)* with *a* denoting AR(1) rho and *n* denoting number of observations,

$$
\operatorname{var}(\bar{X}) =\sigma^{2}\left[1+\delta_{n}(a)\right] n^{-1}=\sigma^{2} c_{n}(a) n^{-1},
$$
with
$$
\delta_{n}=\frac{2 a}{1-a}\left[1-n^{-1} \frac{1}{1-a}+n^{-1} \frac{a^{n}}{1-a}\right] .
$$

From these equations, I would expect I can get the corrected variance by dividing the calculated variance with c(a). Or, dividing calculated standard error by square-root of c(a) to get the corrected estimation of standard deviation.

Putting these into my data-generating R codes, I noticed 2 things and have 2 questions:

1. **The square-root of the correction factor has to be applied.
   Why is that so?** (See the code - I needed to apply sqrt(ca) to get the ***corrected variance***. I couldn't figure out  why from the equations stated in the references)
2. **The performance of the correction factor seems to be the worst when rho approaches 0.5 (or -0.5). Why?** And is there some further adjustment I can do?

Sample R codes below.
I applied the correction factor according to estimated AR(1) from acf instead of the specified rho because it is always a bit smaller than what I specified.

```
SD <- 1
n <- 100 # number of observations in one time series
nsim <- 500 # number of repetitions in simulation

colSdApply <- function(x, ...)apply(X=x, MARGIN=2, FUN=sd, ...)
decimal <- function(x, k) trimws(format(round(x, k), nsmall=k))

ca <- function(x){ 
  # see section 1.1 of Beran (1994)
  x<- abs(x)
  cf <- 1+2*x/(1-x) # eq. 1.14
  cf.smallN <- cf*(1-(1/(1-x)/n+ x^n/(1-x)/n)) # eq 1.12
  # see correction factor k in https://ljmartin.github.io/technical-notes/stats/estimators-autocorrelated/
  delta <- ((n-1)*x - n*x^2 + x^(n+1))/(1-x)^2
  corrk <- sqrt((1+2*delta/n)/(1-2*delta/(n*(n-1))))
  cf.smallN # or return corrk
}

test_arimasim = function(AR){
  ts <- arima.sim(list(order=c(1,0,0), ar=AR), n=n, sd=SD)
  resacf <- acf(ts,plot = FALSE)
  return(list(ts,resacf$acf[2]))
}

adjustedSD <- function(x){
  df.VAR <-  data.frame(AR = unlist(t(x)[,2]))
  df.VAR$SD <- colSdApply(do.call(cbind, x[1,]))
  df.VAR$ca <- ca(df.VAR$AR)
  df.VAR$adjvar <- df.VAR$SD^2 / sqrt(df.VAR$ca)
  df.VAR$adjSD <- sqrt(df.VAR$adjvar)
  paste0("AR(empirical)=",decimal(mean(df.VAR$AR),2),
         " | Naive SD=",decimal(mean(df.VAR$SD),2),
         " | Corrected SD=",decimal(mean(df.VAR$adjSD),2),
     " | Correction Factor=",decimal(mean(df.VAR$ca),2))
}

sdresult <- function(AR){
  sim.arima <- (replicate(nsim,test_arimasim(AR),simplify = TRUE))
  paste0("AR(input)=", decimal(AR,1)," | ",adjustedSD(sim.arima))
}

sapply((seq_len(19)-10)/10,sdresult)
```

Reference:

> Beran, J. (1994). Statistics for long-memory processes. Routledge.
> (mentioned in https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/421007/358964)
>
> Bence, J. R. (1995). Analysis of short time series: correcting for autocorrelation. Ecology, 76(2), 628-639.
> (mentioned in https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/463634/358964)